# WebRTC: ICE, STUN and TURN, but can't I just use my SignalR.NET connection?

Tags: .net, signalr, webrtc

I'm currently developing a conferencing video web application. I decided to go the WebRTC route, but it is still a bit unclear to me how to use it properly.

My application is made in ASP.NET MVC and I also added SignalR for chat/notification functionality. I need to make a live connection between the users and also record the stream of the speaker. The recording of the speaker now works.

I made a page that starts a mediarecorder to capture the users webcam, then I attached to the ondataavailable event to capture the webcam data:

```
mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = function (e) {

    console.log('Data received: ', e);

    // Increase index
    streamindex++;

    // Save client dates
    var stopdate = new Date();
    var startdate = olddate;
    olddate = stopdate;

    // Format dates
    var startdatestr =
        startdate.getFullYear() + "-" +
        startdate.getMonth() + "-" +
        startdate.getDate() + " " +
        startdate.getHours() + ':' +
        startdate.getMinutes() + ':' +
        startdate.getSeconds() + '.' +
        startdate.getMilliseconds();

    var stopdatestr =
        stopdate.getFullYear() + "-" +
        stopdate.getMonth() + "-" +
        stopdate.getDate() + " " +
        stopdate.getHours() + ':' +
        stopdate.getMinutes() + ':' +
        stopdate.getSeconds() + '.' +
        stopdate.getMilliseconds();

    // Send data to server
    $.ajax({
        url: '/Upload?StreamId=' + streamid + '&Index=' + streamindex + '&StartDate=' + startdatestr + '&StopDate=' + stopdatestr,
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: 'application/octet-stream',
        data: e.data,
        processData: false
    });
};
```

On the server I save the data and this seems to work perfectly.

Now I want to make a peer to peer connection between the clients, I've looked online how to do this, but I found out I have to use STUN and TURN servers to create the connection. Since I use .NET I don't really like the idea of having to deploy nodejs servers. I found this code online:

```
function call() {
    callButton.disabled = true;
    hangupButton.disabled = false;
    trace("Starting call");

    if (localStream.getVideoTracks().length > 0) {
        trace('Using video device: ' + localStream.getVideoTracks()[0].label);
    }
    if (localStream.getAudioTracks().length > 0) {
        trace('Using audio device: ' + localStream.getAudioTracks()[0].label);
    }

    var servers = null;

    localPeerConnection = new RTCPeerConnection(servers);
    trace("Created local peer connection object localPeerConnection");
    localPeerConnection.onicecandidate = gotLocalIceCandidate;

    remotePeerConnection = new RTCPeerConnection(servers);
    trace("Created remote peer connection object remotePeerConnection");
    remotePeerConnection.onicecandidate = gotRemoteIceCandidate;
    remotePeerConnection.onaddstream = gotRemoteStream;

    localPeerConnection.addStream(localStream);
    trace("Added localStream to localPeerConnection");
    localPeerConnection.createOffer(gotLocalDescription, handleError);
}

function gotLocalDescription(description) {
    localPeerConnection.setLocalDescription(description);
    trace("Offer from localPeerConnection: \n" + description.sdp);
    remotePeerConnection.setRemoteDescription(description);
    remotePeerConnection.createAnswer(gotRemoteDescription, handleError);
}

function gotRemoteDescription(description) {
    remotePeerConnection.setLocalDescription(description);
    trace("Answer from remotePeerConnection: \n" + description.sdp);
    localPeerConnection.setRemoteDescription(description);
}

function hangup() {
    trace("Ending call");
    localPeerConnection.close();
    remotePeerConnection.close();
    localPeerConnection = null;
    remotePeerConnection = null;
    hangupButton.disabled = true;
    callButton.disabled = false;
}

function gotRemoteStream(event) {
    remoteVideo.src = URL.createObjectURL(event.stream);
    trace("Received remote stream");
}

function gotLocalIceCandidate(event) {
    if (event.candidate) {
        remotePeerConnection.addIceCandidate(new RTCIceCandidate(event.candidate));
        trace("Local ICE candidate: \n" + event.candidate.candidate);
    }
}

function gotRemoteIceCandidate(event) {
    if (event.candidate) {
        localPeerConnection.addIceCandidate(new RTCIceCandidate(event.candidate));
        trace("Remote ICE candidate: \n " + event.candidate.candidate);
    }
}
```

This example uses a local RTCPeerConnection to send the video/audio data. If I want to use this example online I should add the STUN / TURN servers to the "servers" variable. But since I have no STUN / TURN servers, is there any way I can make the WebRTC connection using SignalR?

(SignalR allows me to send messages / data between the clients very easily)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, turned out I did have to use a Turn/Stun server, because it tries to setup a peer-to-peer connection between clients and has support for all WebRTC functions.

On the other hand, WebRTC does require you to have your own signalling service to setup the connection between clients. This is where SignalR comes in, when setting up the RTCPeerConnection you need to setup some event handlers like the "onicecandidate" and "onaddstream" which you need to signal to the other client.

I found this example online: https://www.skylinetechnologies.com/Blog/Skyline-Blog/February-2013/Peer-to-Peer-Media-Streaming-with-WebRTC-and-Signa

```
(function () {
    var _myConnection,
        _myMediaStream;

    function _createConnection(onStreamAddedCallback) {
        // Create a new PeerConnection
        var connection = new webkitRTCPeerConnection(null);

        // ICE Candidate Callback
        connection.onicecandidate = function (event) {
            if (event.candidate) {
                hub.server.send(JSON.stringify({ "candidate": event.candidate }));
            }
        };

        // Negotiation needed callback
        connection.onnegotiationneeded = function () {
            connection.createOffer(function (desc) {
                connection.setLocalDescription(desc, function () {
                    hub.server.send(JSON.stringify({ "sdp": connection.localDescription }));
                });
            });
        };

        // Stream handler
        connection.onaddstream = onStreamAddedCallback;

        return connection;
    }

    // Set Up SignalR Signaler
    var hub = $.connection.webRtcHub;
    $.support.cors = true;
    $.connection.hub.url = '/signalr/hubs';
    $.connection.hub.start({ xdomain: true }, function () {
        console.log('connected to hub.');
        init();
    });

    hub.client.newMessage = function (data) {
        var message = JSON.parse(data),
            connection = _myConnection || _createConnection(onAddStream);

        if (message.sdp) {
            connection.setRemoteDescription(new RTCSessionDescription(message.sdp), function () {
                if (connection.remoteDescription.type == "offer") {
                    console.log('received offer, sending response...');
                    connection.createAnswer(function (desc) {
                        connection.setLocalDescription(desc, function () {
                            hub.server.send(JSON.stringify({ "sdp": connection.localDescription }));
                        });
                    });
                }
            });
        } else if (message.candidate) {
            console.log('adding ice candidate...');
            connection.addIceCandidate(new RTCIceCandidate(message.candidate));
        }

        _myConnection = connection;
    };

    function onAddStream(event) {
        console.log('Adding stream id: ' + event.stream.id);

        var newVideoElement = document.createElement('video');
        newVideoElement.className = 'video';
        newVideoElement.src = window.webkitURL.createObjectURL(event.stream);
        newVideoElement.autoplay = 'autoplay';

        document.querySelector('body').appendChild(newVideoElement);
    }

    function init() {
        navigator.webkitGetUserMedia(
                {
                    // Request Permissions
                    video: true,
                    audio: true
                },
                function (stream) { // succcess callback
                    var videoElement = document.querySelector('.video.mine');

                    _myMediaStream = stream;
                    videoElement.src = window.webkitURL.createObjectURL(_myMediaStream);

                    console.log('my stream id: ' + stream.id);

                    $('#startBtn').removeAttr('disabled');
                },
                function (error) { // error callback
                    alert(JSON.stringify(error));
                }
            );

        $('#startBtn').click(function () {
            _myConnection = _createConnection(onAddStream);
            _myConnection.addStream(_myMediaStream);

            // done being able to work
            $('#startBtn').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        });
    }
})();
```

I used this code to write my own client en server library (I want to have a 1 to many video conferencing system). You can use the stream you get from navigator.webkitGetUserMedia to hookup multiple RTCPeerConnections. After knowing this part, it all fell into place.

Comment: Hi, what is different in your working solution to your non-working solution?
Are you able to get it working without using STUN or TURN servers? 
The only difference i can see is your solution uses "webkitRTCPeerConnection"

Comment: Old question, no it's not possible to get it working without stun/turn unless one of your participants has a direct connection to the internet (with router).

Comment: @ikwillem Can you please share a working sample, I need to understand all the moving parts. Thanks

Comment: Hey @ikwillem, Did you find the solution to this question?

Comment: This is a old question, today "onAddStream" and "AddStream" have been depriciated. So the code most likely doesn't work anymore. There are multiple newer samples available on: https://webrtc.github.io/samples/ this was also very helpfull https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebRTC_API/Signaling_and_video_calling